# Programmatically detect if menu option has implemented on application

Tags: android, menu

I am having problem to show animation for Menu option in my project on some devices. Because some device doesn't have hardware menu key option but it shows in Action Bar. Please help me how to detect menu option programmatically & to show animation for that one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to detect if devices has hardware menu button:

```
ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
```

Comment: yes already implemented, but if device don't have hardware menu button then how to detect? (used nexus device)

Comment: just check using `if(ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey()){ //has menu button }else{ //do action }`. Actually if you are using ActionBar from support library (v7) it's already have auto-detect function for menu button.